Apache error AH00428: Parent: child process 4740 exited with status 255 -- Restarting
I wrote a PHP program on Windows Server 2012 R2, but it always reports a 502 error. The error message is as follows:
[pid 5312:tid 444] AH00428: Parent: child process 4740 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[pid 5312:tid 444] AH00455: Apache/2.4.25 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2k configured -- resuming normal operations
[pid 5312:tid 444] AH00456: Server built: Dec 16 2016 23:05:57
[pid 5312:tid 444] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\wwwroot\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d D:/wwwroot/xampp/apache'
[pid 5312:tid 444] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2144
[pid 2144:tid 348] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
The Windows error is as follows:
错误应用程序名称: httpd.exe，版本: 2.4.25.0，时间戳: 0x5854e3d6
错误模块名称: ntdll.dll，版本: 6.3.9600.20718，时间戳: 0x636f3964
异常代码: 0xc0000374
错误偏移量: 0x00000000000f1f50
错误进程 ID: 0x1788
错误应用程序启动时间: 0x01db0cc02aad3070
错误应用程序路径: D:\wwwroot\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
错误模块路径: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
报告 ID: 3ddc205c-78b6-11ef-8173-87881bfea60f
错误程序包全名:
错误程序包相对应用程序 ID:
The Apache version is 2.4.25. The MySQL version is 8.0.
I expect to resolve the 502 issue. I have checked the Apache logs, PHP program logs, and MySQL logs, but I still haven't been able to find a solution.

Apache 2.4.25 is pretty outdated, and Windows Server 2012 R2 is more than ten years old, and out of support! Please don't use unsupported software
